# Sanity check on this DAC reconstruction filter design

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, schematics, dac, active-filter

I've altered a reconstruction filter circuit to use the [LTC728XT](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2109191830_Linearin-LTC728XT14-R6_C2888133.pdf) instead of the [AD8608](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8605_8606_8608.pdf) op-amp used in the example circuit below. Is anyone able to see any issues with my attempt? This is being used as part of a dsp project and the recommended AD8606 is end of line from what I gather + way too expensive. I'll need 4 outputs hence the decision to use an op-amp with 14 pins.

[image: Alternative circuit]

[image: Example circuit]
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're doing single-ended supply, you'll need DC bias on your inputs. Is that built into your DAC output? The output already has DC blocking.

Comment: Hi @DaveTweed, yes there is a 1.5V DC bias from the DAC

Comment: @I_love_dsp: Is this a Low Pass Filter? If yes, which elements should I change it's values in order to achieve the cutoff frequency I want?